# Select date SQL with replace month to numeric not working?

Tags: php, sql, database

I have a table containing data like this:

```
|-------|-------------------|
|   id  |       expired     |
|-------|-------------------|
|   1   |   03 Maret 2018   |
|   2   |   06 Juli 2018    |
|   3   |   02 April 2018   |
|   4   |   22 Agustus 2018 |
|   5   |   19 Juli 2018    |
|   6   |   27 Januari 2018 |
|   7   |   18 Mei 2018     |
|   8   |   13 Oktober 2018 |
|_______|___________________|
```

In the `expired` column, I use the language of `INDONESIA`, not `English`.

I would like to separate all content that has been `expired` on the website.

If now the date `(08 Maret 2018)`, then there should be 2 items that have been expired, including:

```
id = 1
id = 6
```

But I get different results, and the result is:

```
id = 1
id = 2
id = 3
```

I know these unsuitable results are caused by `"month"` that are not assigned as numbers. But I've changed it to SQL.

**Here's the code I use:**

```
$replace_month = "replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(expired, 'Januari', '01'), 'Februari', '02'), 'Maret', '03'), 'April', '04'), 'Mei', '05'), 'Juni', '06'), 'Juli', '07'), 'Agustus', '08'), 'September', '09'), 'Oktober', '10'), 'November', '11'), 'Desember', '12')";

$dateNow = date('d m Y');

$sql = $db->query("SELECT id FROM MyTable WHERE '$dateNow' > $replace_month");

while($row = $sql->fetch_array()) {
    echo 'ID : ' . $row['id'] . '<br>';
}
```

The result is:

```
1
2
3
```

Whereas I expect is:

```
1
6
```

When running SQL, the `"month"` in the `expired` column is already set as a number, for example `27 01 2018`, but why is the result still wrong?

The error lies in months that do not count, so it's possible to count only dates and years.

So for example now dated `March 08, 2018`, then the script is only looking for the date below `08 only`. As for the month is ignored. So that's what makes my code not working properly.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) More importantly, fix your data model so the date is stored as a native *date* format, rather than as a string.  That is the root cause of this problem.

Comment: maybe any suggestions other than changing the date format on my database? because the number of posts is rather a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think the query compares dates as string not date format. so how about changing to date format like this. I hope this code can work.

mysql case:

```
$sql = $db->query("SELECT id FROM MyTable WHERE 
STR_TO_DATE('$dateNow', '%d %m %Y') > STR_TO_DATE(expired, '%d %M %Y')");
```

oracle case:

```
$sql = $db->query("SELECT id FROM MyTable WHERE 
TO_DATE('$dateNow', 'DD MM YYYY') > TO_DATE(expired, 'DD MONTH YYYY')");
```

if expired is date format, no need to change to date format.
i don't know the DBMS can support the month string. 
if not, use STR_TO_DATE($expired, '%d %m %Y').